# Error with using makeCopy() method in DocsList class (in google apps script)

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to copy a file (Google presentation) in the Google drive using the app script (see below). However, when I execute the small script, the following message pops ups:

> File Pres123 New must be converted to a Google document first. (line 3)

Does someone has a hint for me regarding what I'm doing wrong?

```
function myFunction() { <br>
  var blafile = DocsList.getFileById("11lyU7q7TjPl89Ryjl_rU9YAZnGBCfSiRyxWlZfvOF-E"); <br>
  var newfile = blafile.makeCopy(); <br>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a [known issue](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=874), copying files only work for Documents and Spreadsheets. You should *star* the issue to keep track of updates and kind of vote for it.